# Running USE-2 vs THHW-2

Tags: wiring

Due to a boneheaded "compromise" of the 2" buried conduit that I was planning to run to a 125 amp sub-panel in an outbuilding, I don't know now if I should use USE-2 vs.THHW-2.

The conduit is probably not waterproof now and might even be worse because it could be a waterline instead. 100' buried 2" PVC conduit maxed at 360 degrees. Pulling 3 1/0 aluminum conduit and one #6 copper ground.

The question is that now that I know there will be water in the conduit should I use USE-2 instead of THHW-2 for the conduit and a sheathed #6 copper. I can still pull but is there a difference in pulling USE vs THHW? Got a lot of bends.

Comment: Buried conduit must always be considered damp/wet.

Comment: The "W" is for water resistant. Pulling wires 100' won't be easy. But it will be a **lot** easier than pulling cable 100'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure they make THHW-2 (it's not shown in 310.4), the table shows THHW but I would be surprised if you could find it, for example at [Platt.com](https://www.platt.com/s/search?q=thhw), most sizes show none in stock.

If you have a complete conduit system go to a parts house instead of a national retail store and get XHHW-2, the W gives you wet (underground) location. Should be cheaper than USE-2, and much easier to pull because the insulation is more slick and smaller.

Pricing shown on Platt.com is a little higher than you should expect to pay if you handle yourself wisely.